# Reduce operation

Tags: ruby, reduce

This is in some lecture slides of mine:

```
words = %w{cat sheep bear}
words.reduce do |memo, word| memo.length > word.length ? memo : word end
#=> "sheep"
```

I don't understand what is going on in this `reduce` operation. I do not understand why `"sheep"` is printed.

I didn't understand what was going on in the `memo`, `word` operation, but I think that I figured out that it simply takes the longest word and returns it.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#comment17104_253896

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ahhh i see, I'll edit it to be more specific, sorry

Answer (score 3):

Read the documentation for [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), specifically:

> If you specify a block, then for each element in enum the block is
>   passed an accumulator value (memo) and the element...the result becomes the new
>   value for memo. At the end of the iteration, the final value of memo
>   is the return value for the method.

For a little added clarity, your block can be rewritten as:

```
words.reduce do |longest, word|
  if longest.length > word.length
    longest
  else
    word
  end
end
```

The block to reduce takes two parameters: the current value of the reduction (also called the *memo*, or *accumulator*), and the current element being processed. The value that the block returns is what it uses as the memo for the next iteration.

In English, your reduction here is looking at each word in the array and keeping the longest word that it sees after each iteration. The net result is that the `reduce` expression used here is returning the longest word in the array, which is `sheep`.

If you were to step through the execution one iteration at a time, you'd see the following values being passed to the block:

- Iteration 0

  - `longest = "cat"`, `word = "cat"`
  - An initial value was not specified for the memo, so `reduce` uses the first value in the array ("cat") as the default memo
  - "cat" remains our memo
- Iteration 1

  - `longest = "cat"`, `word = "sheep"`
  - Because "sheep" is longer than "cat", "sheep" becomes our new memo
- Iteration 2

  - `longest = "sheep"`, `word = "bear"`
  - "sheep" is longer than "bear", so it remains as our memo
- Complete

  - We've iterated through the entire array, and the resulting value for the `reduce` call is the value of our current memo, "sheep"

Reduce is also known as [folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) in some languages. The term "folding" makes intuitive sense as you're rolling or folding each value in the array into some kind of aggregate (reduced) final value.

Comment: thank you, I'm new to Ruby so the syntax is what's tripping me up the most.

Comment: Ruby's syntax is terse and sometimes magical. You should be sure to have a strong grasp of blocks and how they work before diving into higher-level array operations like `reduce`, `map`, etc., since everything builds on the concept of blocks. I'll try to elaborate a bit in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than explain it, I want to show you the iteration process..

```
words = %w{cat sheep bear}
words.reduce do |memo, word|
  memo.length > word.length ? memo : word
end
```

The variable `words` == ['cat', 'sheep', 'bear']

```
# First iteration uses 'cat' and 'sheep'
'cat'.length > 'sheep'.length ? 'cat' : 'sheep'
# This ternary returns 'sheep' because 'sheep' is longer than 'cat'
```

Currently: `memo` within the `reduce` method == 'sheep'

```
# Second iteration uses `memo` which == 'sheep'
# Also uses 'bear'
'sheep'.length > 'bear'.length ? 'sheep' : 'bear'
# `sheep is longer than 'bear', so the ternary is true which returns `sheep`
```

Currently: `memo` == 'sheep'

Reduce method ends since it is done iterating the array. Reduce method returns the `memo` which is set to `'sheep'`

Hopefully this didn't confuse you. I thought maybe showing the individual iterations would be nice to see

Answer (score 0):

First, since you have not specified default value for reduce it will be set to 'cat'. So, now memo is 'cat'.
Second, you code inside reduce method returns boolean value. By default, if this expression is true - then the default value will be reassigned. That is why memo is 'sheep'.
The last one, since there are no more words longer than 'sheep' it will be returned.

Comment: What do you mean by "default value for reduce"? The code inside the block does not return a boolean value. Not clear what you mean by "By default, ... the default value will be reassigned."